# Ideal generated by two coprime polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $f(x)$, $g(x)$ be two univariate, coprime, integer polynomials and let $I=\big(f(x),g(x)\big)$ the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ generated by $f, g$. Let $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$, that is, the elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ which can be expressed as linear combinations of $f(x), g(x)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$ is clearly an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$. The following argument shows that, **given two coprime integer polynomials $f,g$, the ideal $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ has always non zero elements**:

If $f,g$ are considered as elements of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, Bezout's identity tells us that there exists a pair of unique rational polynomials $U(x)$, $V(x)$ with $\deg U<\deg g$, $\deg V<\deg f$ such that
$$
U(x)f(x)+V(x)g(x)=1
$$
Thus, clearing denominators in the above identity, we get that there exists a pair of unique integer polynomials $u(x)$, $v(x)$ with $\deg u<\deg g$, $\deg v<\deg f$ such that
$$
u(x)f(x)+v(x)g(x)=c
$$
where $c$ is the $lcm$ of the denominators of $U,V$ and: $u=cU$, $v=cV$. Thus: $0 \neq c\in I \cap \mathbb{Z}$.

**Question $1$:** Can we determine a sufficient and necessary condition such that: $\mathbb{Z}\subset I \cap \mathbb{Z}$?

**Question $2$:** Is there a general method for determining the least positive generator of $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$ ?

References:

- [Bezout relation with integral coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768717/bezout-relation-with-integral-coefficients)
- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248488/reduced-resultants-and-bezouts-identity
- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17501/the-resultant-and-the-ideal-generated-by-two-polynomials-in-mathbbzx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: [This was also posted to mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/248574/1916). Please note that [crossposting between SE sites is highly frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068) - try one site first, and if you don't get a satisfactory response, ask a moderator to **migrate** the question to a different site. If you insist on posting in many sites, at least provide links to the other posts - as you can imagine, it would be frustrating for someone to put time into answering your question here, only to find out that you'd already gotten an answer elsewhere.

Comment: With any luck, Gerry M. will answer on MO. He is in Australia and should be  awake soon. You might as well just write to him.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles: ok thank you for the information! meanwhile, should i delete the post here?

Comment: @KonKan: You can, or you can also provide a link on each copy to the other copy.

Comment: you already did half the way. The other half is: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/248574/ideal-generated-by-two-univariate-coprime-integer-polynomials